# R: matching coordinates from one (large) data frame into grid cells from another (large) data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a large data frame (~200,000 rows) that contains X-Y coordinates, e.g.:

```
points <- data.frame(X = c(1,3,2,5,4), Y = c(4,3,2,2,1))
```

And another large data frame (~1,000,000 rows) that contains the corner cells of a spatial (rectangular) grid, e.g.:

```
MINX <- rep(0.5:5.5,6)
MINY <- rep(0.5:5.5,each=6)
grid <- data.frame(GridID = 1:36, MINX, MINY, MAXX = MINX+1, MAXY = MINY+1)
```

I would like to add a column to the "points" data frame that identified the ID of the grid the point is located in:

```
X Y GridID
1 4     19
3 3     15
2 2      8
5 2     11
4 1      4
```

I can think of several ways to do this, using loops, using combinations of apply and match, even pulling out some big spatial gun from `sp` or `maptools`.  But all are prohibitively slow.  I have a hunch there's some `data.table()` one liner that could pull this off in reasonable time.  Do any gurus have an idea?

(For the record, this is how I got the grid cell ID's above:

```
pt.minx <- apply(points,1, 
             function(foo) max(unique(grid)$MINX[unique(grid)$MINX < foo[1]]))
pt.miny <- apply(points,1, 
             function(foo) max(unique(grid)$MINY[unique(grid)$MINY < foo[2]]))
with(grid, GridID[match(pt.minx+1i*pt.miny, MINX + 1i*MINY)])
```

I can't tell from here whether it's slick or hideous - either way the apply function is way too slow for the complete data frame.)

Comment: If your grid is rectangular and regular, you could use `findInterval` (and wouldn't need `MAXX` and `MAXY`).

Comment: Your input and output X and Y don't match.

Comment: @Hong Sorry - fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need two merges with rolling:

```
grid = data.table(grid, key = 'MINX')
points = data.table(points, key = 'X')

# first merge to find correct MAXX
intermediate = grid[points, roll = Inf][, list(MAXX, X = MINX, Y)]

# now merge by Y
setkey(intermediate, MAXX, Y)
setkey(grid, MAXX, MINY)
grid[intermediate, roll = Inf][, list(X, Y = MINY, GridID)]
#   X Y GridID
#1: 1 4     19
#2: 2 2      8
#3: 3 3     15
#4: 4 1      4
#5: 5 2     11
```

Comment: Brilliant.  3.4 seconds to obtain the grid-cells for the complete data.

Answer (score 3):

Doing it the SQL[df] way:

```
require(sqldf)
sqldf("select X, Y, GridID from grid, pts
       where MINX < X and X < MAXX and MINY < Y and Y < MAXY")
```

---

Expanding on @Roland's comment, you can use `findInterval` here:

```
MINX <- MINY <- 0.5:5.5
x <- findInterval(pts$X, MINX)
y <- findInterval(pts$Y, MINY)
grid$GridID[match(MINX[x]+1i*MINY[y], grid$MINX+1i*grid$MINY)]
```

Nice trick to coerce to complex for 2-dimensional matching, btw.

Comment: Nice, thanks for super-fast responses.  I like the "chatty" sql syntax (I've never used if before)...  It is still pretty slow: i.e. a heavily truncated dataset where `grid` had 1892 rows, and `points` has 60000 rows took 3 minutes.  But with some heavy chunking of the data, this could work.  Will play with this more tomorrow.