# R data.table: roll points to a grid

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I am currently trying to use the roll option of data.table to merge two tables, because I read that it is really nice and efficient. Unfortunately, no matter how I try it, I always get wrong results. Either I have lots of NAs in the resulting data table, I have the wrong values or I simply get an error message that the merge is not possible.
What makes things a little bit more complicated than the usual time series case documented and explained everywhere about the roll option is that I need a 2D roll. Meaning I have points in 2d (imagine for examples pixels of an image) that I want to roll to a 2D grid.
Below you find a short code example of what I try to achieve. The version posted is as I would expect things to work, based on this answer: [R: matching coordinates from one (large) data frame into grid cells from another (large) data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073861/r-matching-coordinates-from-one-large-data-frame-into-grid-cells-from-another/18083544#18083544), but I get an error message. I can fix this error by removing the points of the grid from the data, but that is not what I'm aiming at, and also doesn't produce the desired output (see check in the last line).

```
data = data.table(CJ(
  x = seq(0,10,0.1),
  y = seq(0,10,0.1)
))

grid = data.table(CJ(
  x = seq(0,10,1),
  y = seq(0,10,1)
))

grid[, label := x*y]

setkey(data, x)
setkey(grid, x)
intermediate = grid[data, roll = Inf][, list(x,y = i.y,label)]

setkey(intermediate, y)
setkey(grid, y)
result = grid[intermediate, roll = Inf][, list(x = i.x, y, label)]
unique(result$label == floor(result$x)*floor(result$y))
```

I know that in this example, I could simply do

```
data[, label := floor(x)*floor(y)]
```

but in the setting I want to use the roll, the label is computed by a difficult process on the grid that can't be easily applied to the data itself.

If anyone could tell me how to get the desired result, and maybe also point out where I went wrong in trying to apply the answer linked above, that would really be great.

Comment: Are you sure your setup is correct? In the question you link, each cell in the grid has 4 points associated with it, as well as a unique id. Your `grid` only has 2 points per cell, with repeated ids.

Answer (score 1):

I think the complication is because the other question has unique X and unique Y coordinates whereas in this case, there are multiple values of Y for each X.

Here is an another approach to use the same rolling join, and filter straight away for the `grid$Y` below `data$Y` and then choose the largest such `grid$Y`:

```
data[, c("cX", "cY") := .(X, Y)]
result <- grid[data, on=.(X), roll=Inf, by=.EACHI, 
    .(X=cX, Y=cY, LABEL=last(LABEL[x.Y<=i.Y]))][, (1) := NULL]
```

`result`:

```
        X    Y LABEL
    1:  0  0.0     0
    2:  0  0.1     0
    3:  0  0.2     0
    4:  0  0.3     0
    5:  0  0.4     0
   ---              
10197: 10  9.6    90
10198: 10  9.7    90
10199: 10  9.8    90
10200: 10  9.9    90
10201: 10 10.0   100
```

check:

```
result[abs(LABEL - floor(X)*floor(Y)) > 1e-10]
#Empty data.table (0 rows and 3 cols): X,Y,LABEL
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
data = data.table(CJ(X=seq(0,10,0.1), Y=seq(0,10,0.1)))
grid = data.table(CJ(X=seq(0,10,1), Y=seq(0,10,1)))[, LABEL := X*Y]
```